# Is there a way for a Blazor component to read its container page class attribute?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I know, there are `CascadedParameter`s, but they require `CascadingValue`s to work.

OK, previous description of the problem was vague. So here's simpler.

Imagine a Blazor page:

```
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize, NavMenu(1, "My first page", "view_module", HeaderText = "Hello!")]

<MyCommonPageHeader/>
```

Why the `NavMenu` attribute? I made it up, it's some metadata that allows me to generate a navigation menu with a link to each configured page.

My goal is to design `MyCommonPageHeader` component, to read the custom attribute (`NavMenuAttribute`) and to use it to display the header on the page.

I've already done that this way:

```
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize, NavMenu(1, "My first page", "view_module", HeaderText = "Hello!")]

<MyCommonPageHeader Page="this"/>
```

I just have to pass `this` to each of my component instance.
I just want to make sure there's no shortcut here, no other way for the component to get to the containing page class.

BTW, here's `NavMenuAttribute` source, if you're curious:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Woof.Blazor {

    public class NavMenuAttribute : Attribute {

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public string HeaderText { get; set; }

        public int Order { get; set; }

        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; } = true;

        public NavMenuAttribute(int order, string displayName, string icon) {
            Order = order;
            DisplayName = displayName;
            Icon = icon;
        }

    }

}
```

Just metadata. Nothing else. I describe the page in the attribute line, now everything else in my app uses this description, so I don't have to repeat anything more than once.

Comment: I read your question 3 times and still can't understand what you need exactly. You have 3 components? A Page where inside you have a menu and another component?

Comment: @Vencovsky No, the menu is outside. Create a sample Blazor application in VS. On the left - there is a thingie like NavMenu. Static markup in the example, but I made a component that dynamically creates such menu from all pages in my assembly that have appropriate attributes. But on each page, I have a special component `PageHeader`, that is a `<h3>` with an icon on the left. I want that header to read the page class attribute. I've found workaround: I made `PageHeader` accept `Page` attribute, I pass `this` to it.

Comment: I think you're on the right track - I think you need s parameter, whether an explicit one or a cascading